# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor Angular 9

Tags: json, angular, api, asp.net-web-api, angular9

I tried so many solutions none of them are not working. please help me to solve this. I need to loop through JSON objects. below is what I tried and my JSON code. I can print the Section name in tr tag but I cannot print the School object Name in the tr tag.

service.ts

```
  getSections(): Observable<Section> {
     return this.http
      .get<Section>(this.apiUrl + 'sections/all')
      .pipe(
      retry(2),
       catchError(this.handleError),
      );
  }
```

Component.ts

```
 getSections() {
  this.service.getSections().subscribe(response => {
  Object.assign(this.sectionData, response);
  console.log(response);
  });
}
```

component.html

```
   <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Section Name</th>
      <th>School Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let pro of sectionData ;let i=index">
      <td [hidden]="true">{{pro.sectionID}}</td>
      <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{pro.Name}}</td>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let sch of pro.School">
        <td>{{sch.Name}}</td>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

My JSON

```
[{
"$id": "1",
"SectionID": 1,
"SchoolID": 6,
"Name": "Grade 1",
"Active": true,
"Tstamp": null,
"Classes": [],
"School": {
    "$id": "2",
    "SchoolID": 6,
    "Name": "Yalpanam",
    "AlternativeName": "سصر ءصيص",
    "TelephoneNumber": "16556489",
    "URL": "",
    "EmailID": "",
    "Longitude": null,
    "Latitude": null,
    "Active": true,
    "Tstamp": null,
    "ClassSections": [],
    "NonStaffs": [],
    "Principals": [],
    "Students": []
}
}]
```

The error which I get is
[Error Msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhjZr.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you JSON, `School` is not an array - it is an object. So you can't iterate over it. To fix that, in your markup change:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let sch of pro.School">
    <td>{{sch.Name}}</td>
  </ng-container>
```

to simply

```
  <td>{{pro.School?.Name}}</td>
```

Comment: You are life savior bro. Thank you I spend 3 days finding a solution. It's worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Remember to mark this answer as a correct one then.